# Including data/datakey in an HTML (SVG) element

Tags: javascript, html

In my code behind, I'm using a constant String and String.Format to create a series of svg elements as such:

```
const string BoxTemplate = "<rect x=\"{0}\" y=\"{1}\" height=\"{2}\" width=\"{3}\" fill=\"{4}\" stroke=\"#707070\" onmouseover=\"showToolTip()\"/>";
string s = String.Format(BoxTemplate, x, y, h, w, color);
```

I'm then using a Literal control to render the images.

I'd like to include data or at least a data key in the element for the mouse over or other event to use.  I thought about setting the id to the datakey, but there are some cases where more then one image will reference the same data.

What's the best way to get my javascript function to recognize which element was "moused over" and to access its data/datakey.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `this` as a parameter to your function. You could also add an additional parameter if you have that at rendering time.

This works for me:

```
<html>

    <script>
        function showToolTip(obj, datakey) {
            alert("ID=" + obj.id + " datakey=" + datakey);
        }
    </script>
    <body>
        <svg>
            <rect id="The_ID" x="10" y="10" height="100" width="100" fill="black" stroke="#707070" onmouseover="showToolTip(this, 'datakey1')"/>
        </svg>
        <svg>
            <rect id="The_other_ID" x="110" y="10" height="100" width="100" fill="black" stroke="#707070" onmouseover="showToolTip(this, 'datakey2')"/>
        </svg>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you have it at rendering time you could add it as a parameter to your function. I altered the example to show this.

Comment: Useful, but not all of the problem I was trying to resolve here. Each of these rectangles corresponds to an item in a database. I'm looking to store the datakey somewhere in the element. I'm not sure I can use the id attribute since not all of the data keys will be unique. Thanks. –

Comment: Just re-looked at this and realized I had missed what you were doing.  Storing the key as a literal in the function call. Duh.

Comment: Well, I altered it after your comment. For some reason my comment to your comment was stored over yours.